# using NDK with C++ error

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile an Android project where i have put a C++ code : 
i've followed this [tutorial](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-eclipse-for-develop-android-app.html#comment-form)
but when compiling i get this error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

make: *** No rule to make target `/home/iheb/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/system/NativeCode.c', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/NativeCode/NativeCode.o'.  Stop. AndroidTest         C/C++ Problem

Comment: Post your Android.mk

Comment: I've fixed the error it was the wrong link to the ndk folder